# URL of a custom post type's post format archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, custom-post-type-archives, post-formats

With pretty permalinks enabled, the URL of a Custom Post Format archive would look like this:

```
http://example.com/type/link/
```

And it works for me.

Now, considering that my custom post type archive is located at (where 'bookmarks' is the custom post type's name, registered with `'has_archive' => true`):

```
http://example.com/bookmarks/
```

Isn't the custom post type's post format archive supposed to be located at:

```
http://example.com/bookmarks/type/link/
```

But I get an HTTP 404 Not Found Error. Isn't it how it works? If not, how do I access the custom post type's post format archive?

Comment: Do you mean that "bookmarks" is the taxonomy?  How can it be the custom post type where "type" represents the custom post type?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @gilhamer Edited question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I finally came to know: *By default, WordPress doesn't have (separate) post format archives for custom post types.*